# What Service should receives - a whole entity or an id?

Tags: java, oop, architecture

Imagine that we have some service:

```java
public class SomeService
{
    public void someWorkByEntity(Entity entity)
    {
        int id = entity.getId();

        // here is some work...
    }

    public void someWorkByEntityId(int id)
    {
        // here is some work...
    }
}
```

In fact Service require only entity id.
But write two versions of each method it's too tedious.

So what is better: Service that receives a model or an id?

Comment: If the service only needs an ID why would you hand in the whole entity?

Comment: @xsquared, in future maybe will be used another entity attributes

Comment: It is hard to tell from your provided information. But a general rule of thumb is to always minimize the flow of information. If you later need another attribute the change is made fast. You can even consider passing the second attribute as parameter as well.

Comment: @xsquared, thnx. that's exactly how I feel